# Very slow login and black screen

Tags: linux, debian, kde, login

I have Debian with KDE installed, everything is mostly well except for my login time, recently. Booting my computer is ok, no specific delay, but when I come up to enter the password and press "Enter", there goes a black screen and a two minutes delay, before the Splash screen comes up and session start correctly.
I'm trying to find an explanation to those 2 minutes delay but I can't get anything.

It might be worth noting that I'm currently on an M.2 SSD which makes the delay very unusual to me. I tried disabling the Splash Screen, doesn't change anything. I tried to swap from lightdm to sddm, doesn't change anything.

`systemd-analyze` doesn't seem to return anything unusual.

```
Startup finished in 37.061s (firmware) + 6.377s (loader) + 4.699s (kernel) + 9.528s (userspace) = 57.666s 
graphical.target reached after 9.489s in userspace
```

I installed KSystemLog, here's the log around the time I login.

```
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd Closed Sound System.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd snapd.session-agent.socket: Succeeded.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd Removed slice User Application Slice.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd Reached target Shutdown.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd systemd-exit.service: Succeeded.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd Finished Exit the Session.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd Reached target Exit the Session.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd user@117.service: Succeeded.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd Stopped User Manager for UID 117.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd Stopping User Runtime Directory /run/user/117...
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd run-user-117.mount: Succeeded.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd run-user-117.mount: Succeeded.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd user-runtime-dir@117.service: Succeeded.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd Stopped User Runtime Directory /run/user/117.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd Removed slice User Slice of UID 117.
2021-08-09 11:31 A.M.   systemd user-117.slice: Consumed 1.303s CPU time.
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   dbus-daemon [session uid=1000 pid=2380] Activating service name='org.kde.KSplash' requested by ':1.9' (uid=1000 pid=2387 comm="/usr/bin/startplasma-x11 ")
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   dbus-daemon [session uid=1000 pid=2380] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.KSplash'
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   dbus-daemon [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' unit='upower.service' requested by ':1.63' (uid=1000 pid=2506 comm="/usr/bin/kded5 ")
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   systemd Starting Daemon for power management...
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   dbus-daemon [session uid=1000 pid=2380] Activating service name='org.kde.ActivityManager' requested by ':1.16' (uid=1000 pid=2511 comm="/usr/bin/kwin_x11 ")
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   dbus-daemon [session uid=1000 pid=2380] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.ActivityManager'
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   dbus-daemon [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower'
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   systemd Started Daemon for power management.
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   dbus-daemon [session uid=1000 pid=2380] Activating via systemd: service name='org.kde.kglobalaccel' unit='plasma-kglobalaccel.service' requested by ':1.17' (uid=1000 pid=2561 comm="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/kactivitymanager")
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   systemd Created slice User Background Tasks Slice.
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   systemd Starting KDE Global Shortcuts Server...
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   dbus-daemon [session uid=1000 pid=2380] Successfully activated service 'org.kde.kglobalaccel'
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   systemd Started KDE Global Shortcuts Server.
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   dbus-daemon [session uid=1000 pid=2380] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.20' (uid=1000 pid=2506 comm="/usr/bin/kded5 ")
2021-08-09 11:33 A.M.   dbus-daemon [session uid=1000 pid=2380] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
```

Comment: It sounds like your pc is trying to contact some other system before timing out, perhaps automount, or even it's trying to locate an AAA system such as kerberos or Windows DC.

Comment: I disabled all my automounts (got a few for internal drives, and a NAS on the network), it didn't change anything. And I don't have any DC or any server on my network.  Out of curisoity, what line gave you that hint?

Comment: No line, your logs did not show anything. It was just a hunch.

Comment: If you login directly on a tty, you can run tcpdump and see if it is trying to contact anything. Perhaps it is a DNS as DO said below. Also try adding a new clean user and see if it happens with it.

Comment: Those logs show that it didn't take more than 60 seconds to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Every time I have seen an issue with slow login, it has been down to DNS.
Check /etc/resolv.conf and ensure the IPs in there are valid

Comment: Doesn't seem to be that. I only got my router in there : `nameserver 192.168.0.1`